# jQuery masked input for decimal numbers with dynamic length

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm having a little issue with a masked input with jQuery:
I have a double number input, so I'm trying to use the jQuery input mask by digitalBush:

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/#license

I used this rule to mask my double number input:

```
jQuery('#${escapedId?html}').mask("9?9999999.99");
```

I want to let the user enter double number with correct part between at least of one to eight digits and decimal part with exactly two digits. But above rule is not work and force the user to enter all digits after question sign.

If you know another way or another plugin that could let me get what I want (even if it's without using this plugin), please let me know.

Comment: Digitalbush plugin does not force to enter all digit after ? mark because these are optional. You need to apply it correctly.